# OmniOut + localhost:4002 error

Tags: lightning-out, jsforce, omnistudio, vlocity, omniscript

**Premise**: I want to host my Omniscripts in a third-party CMS system but before that I have to demo that I can display my Omniscripts even on localhost. I followed [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_omniout_43469.htm&type=5) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us8GjZVqSTc). 
My node version is 14.19.1. 
Vlocity__cmt version is 900.477 
node module version of vlocity packages is 900.458.0 
getting proper access token from connected app

**Problem:** I'm getting the following error 
`request.js:35     POST http://localhost:4002/services/apexrest/v1/GenericInvoke/BusinessProcessDisplayController/logUsageInteractionEvent 404 (Not Found)` 
and with some hit and trial I'm managed to get below error 
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mySandboxName.sandbox.lightning.force.com//services/apexrest/vlocity_cmt/v1/GenericInvoke/BusinessProcessDisplayController/logUsageInteractionEvent' from origin 'http://localhost:4002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

**Solutions tried:** I have tried to add

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); And/OR below line
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4002"); And/OR below line
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
```

I have also tried to whitelist localhost but still no luck....

I have tried to find but 'BusinessProcessDisplayController' seems not to be present as a custom class in my org so it could be some internal managed package class.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to add the site's URL to the CORS settings in the SF Org.

Comment: @CarlOrtiz, thanks for the comment... As stated above, CORS setting was already done

Comment: Solution(which worked for me) for anyone who may face this error: 1. mandatory salesforce release update related to domain URL was not done... 2. Access token was getting expired very fast and for initial testing I was using hardcoded access token... So with resolving only these two things I was able to get rid of CORS error :)

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389384&type=1 .... this is a known issue.